# jQuery - random elements from an array using img.draggable (jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, arrays, random

I'm using this code to print 3 draggable images with random start position in a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {$('img.draggable').each(function(i,el){

var tLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*800),
    tTop  = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);

$(el).css({position:'absolute', left: tLeft, top: tTop});

});
$("img.draggable").draggable();
});    
</script>
```

and in a body:

```
<img src="xxx.xxx" class="draggable" width="260px" height="155px">
<img src="xxxx.xxx" class="draggable" width="300px" height="225px">
<img src="xxxx.xxx" class="draggable" width="225px" height="150px">
```

to get the pictures. ( always 3)

Now the code works well, I need one more step:

Is there a way to get always 3 gif images but randomly from a large array ( 10 gif elements for example)

I tried to add the function but the elements losses draggable class.

So, I have 3 draggable elements on a page, with randomly start position, I need to get those  3 elements from larger random array at every refresh.

Sorry for my poor js and thanks a lot for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do

```
$(el).attr('src', genRandomFilename());
```

right after `$(el).css(...`. Then image source will be set before application of draggable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If count of images is fixed i.e. 3, then you can change image src using jQuery. Else you can create image using jQuery and add to page. Then apply draggable function of jQuery UI. It should work.

```
<script>
var imgArray = [];
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("img.draggable").each(function(index, element) {

        var tLeft = Math.floor(Math.random()*800);
        var tTop  = Math.floor(Math.random()*400);

            $(element).css({position:'absolute', left: tLeft, top: tTop});
            $(element).draggable();     

    });
});
</script>


<img src="test.jpg" class="draggable" width="120" height="120">
<img src="test.jpg" class="draggable" width="120" height="120">
<img src="test.jpg" class="draggable" width="120" height="120">
```